# How to set BarChartView barColor?

Tags: objective-c, swift, ios-charts

This is the UI Picture

[image: UI]

I don't know how to set a lightgray color

[image]

I try to use

```
self.chartView.drawGridBackgroundEnabled = YES;
self.chartView.gridBackgroundColor = [UIColor grayColor];
```

But the effect is not what I want

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to enable `BarShadow` Property as mention below:

```
 _barChartView.drawBarShadowEnabled = YES;
```

By default its showing GrayColor for customize Shadow Color you have to set shadow color in `BarChartDataSet` like below :

```
BarChartDataSet *set1 = [[BarChartDataSet alloc] initWithValues:Values];
set1.barShadowColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor]; // Set your custom color here
```

Hope this will help you to show your Custom color in bar shadow.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
UIColor *color = ...;
color = [color colorWithAlphaComponent:0.5f];
```

OR You can try with RGB values.

```
[UIColor colorWithRed:(160/255.0) green:(97/255.0) blue:(5/255.0) alpha:1]
```